# Nuxt, Fire Node Action after Nuxt ends generation

Tags: nuxt.js

In gatsbyjs i have hook like
`export.postBuild = (pages, cb) => { some code after ... }`

Is there any equivalent for nuxt? I want to do some action after generation written in nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the nuxt hooks: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-hooks/

What you search are the generator hooks: https://nuxtjs.org/api/internals-generator#hooks

```
this.nuxt("generate:done", (generator, errors) => {
   //...
})
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
  hooks: {
     generate: {
        done(generator, errors) {
           //... do something
        }
     }
  }
}
```